# Getting all namespaces in certain directory

Tags: c#, reflection

I am trying to find a way to retrieve all the namespaces in our test directory. All classes in the project share a same namespace, so I need to get the class as well. The results I am looking for should look like this

```
Project.ClassA
Project.ClassB
```

Where Project is the namespace and ClassA is the class name. I tried out a function like this...

```
assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(System.Int32));
var groups = assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.IsClass);

foreach(var group in groups)
{
   Console.WriteLine(group);
}
```

However this is returning a bunch of System information among other things, nothing related to what I am looking for. Am I on the right track here? Also, how can I make it look only in the test directory?

Comment: What do you mean by "directory"? You mean the folder on the hard drive that contains all the DLLs for your app? That could be all sorts of stuff.

Comment: "how can I make it look only in the test directory" What is your test-directory? I suppose it´s the directory where you assembly is located, isn´t it? Then why do you use `Assembly.GetAssembly` on a `System`-type?

Comment: Your sample code is listing all of the types from the assembly that contains `System.Int32`, so it's not surprising that you're getting back "a bunch of System information"

Comment: Keep in mind that in .NET the fact that namespaces match folder structure (in your solution) is merely a convention. (This isn't Java.) So you are free to not use folders at all and still have namespaces, or even change the namespace from what the folder name is...or even have two different namespaces in the same file.

Comment: @DavidG Sorry about that, should have been more clear. The test directory is inside the solution.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I am not sure. I know nothing of how to do this, its just the first thing I tried

Comment: So those DLLs aren't part of your project, it's just a collection of random DLL files?

Comment: @DavidG it is a part of my project.

Comment: How can DLLs inside a test folder be part of your project?

Comment: @DavidG I am sorry, this has really nothing to do with a DLL file. I am trying to just write a method that looks in the current project to retrieve these namespace paths. Again, I am sorry if my terminology is not the best

Comment: So you just want all types that are in any DLLs that are loaded as part of your project?

Comment: I am starting to think maybe Assembly is not even what I should be using.. All I am trying to do, is create a function that will return to me the namespace and the class names. like namespace.className, that are found in my project.

Comment: will update my question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you all types that are part of the current app domain (i.e. all the types that are loaded):

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes());
```

If you want to filter that list, just add a `Where` clause:

```
var types = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
    .GetAssemblies()
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(a => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.Namespace) && 
                a.Namespace.StartsWith("Foo"));
```

And do something with them:

```
foreach(var type in types)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Found type {type.Name}");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this! I tried the exact code above but it is throwing a NullReferenceException

Comment: Try now, it's because not all types have a namespace.

Comment: Yes!! This did it, I can tweak this to give me what I need. Thank you so much! :)